# EF Core one-to-many relationship with multiple contexts (databases)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have contexts with entities like this:

```cs
public class CompanyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<StoreModel> Stores { get; set; }
    // Other entities
}
```

```cs
public class DepartmentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<OrderModel> Orders { get; set; }
    // Other entities
}
```

```cs
public class StoreModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderModel> ReceivedOrders { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<OrderModel> PreparedOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderModel> IssuedOrders { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class OrderModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public StoreModel GettingStore { get; set; } 
    public StoreModel PreparingStore { get; set; }
    public StoreModel IssuanceStore { get; set; }
}
```

For example a user makes an order in storeA, but wants to receive it in storeC, and it order will preparing in storeB. And I needs a statiscics about store received/prepared/issued orders.

When I try to create a migrations, EF throws exceptions `"Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'OrderModel.GettingStore' of type 'StoreModel'"` and `"Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'StoreModel.IssuedOrders' of type 'ICollection<OrderModel>'"`. If I understand correctly, this happens because entities are defined in different contexts.

Now I just use next model:

```cs
public class OrderModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public Guid GettingStoreId { get; set; } 
    public Guid PreparingStoreId { get; set; }
    public Guid IssuanceStoreId { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine, but perhaps there are options that allow to create such a structure using navigation properties, with correct relationships between these entities from different contexts(databases).

Comment: EF Core do not work across databases. Also you cannot create cross `DbContext` queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the map of a different database was not placed in tables of different application formats, so think that you have a domain that should be well defined in your application, that way you would have the mapping of your application like this:

```
public class DomainNameContext: DbContext 
{
    public DomainNameContext(): base() 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<StoreModel> Stores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderModel> Orders { get; set; }
        
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       // config mapping methods
    }
}
```

another thing, the relation you are using doesn't work so you can't have a repetition of Orders within the same class because this is not one -> many, this statement means that a StoreModel line can have many lines in the OrderModel this way would be like this

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Details { get; set; }

    public Guid StoreModeId { get; set; } // this part will show the entity framework that this is the fk it will correlate

    public StoreModel StoreModel { get; set; } 
}

public class StoreModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderModel> OrderModels { get; set; } 
}
```

see that if you are wanting to have many StoreModel related to many OrderModel then you need to use many -> many which microsoft documentation foresees to use as well

good to map this within its context it is necessary in OnModelCreating to use its mapping like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // config mapping methods
   modelBuilder.Entity<StoreModel>()
               .HasMany<OrderModel>(g => g.OrderModels )
               .HasForeignkey<Guid>(s => s.StoreModeId )
}
```

you can have a look at the microsoft documentation [enter link description here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx), [enter link description here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

now if you need to map between contexts you will have to use dapper to make separate queries in separate bases the entity has support for that in this link [enter link description here](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-multiple-databases-efcore/)
and then you can make the necessary inner joins so that you can use it but natively this does not exist, I advise you to rethink your database so that it can make more sense to a relational model, perhaps putting types for your StoreModel and OrderModel so you can use the way I wanted the types GettingStore, PreparingStore, IssuanceStore using an enum for this to make it explicit

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed answer. Second, about the type of relationship, I didn't think about many-to-many, because I thought it's just one "Order" :), but I think that's what I need. Third, I can't use enum in my case because I need know Where the order is received/prepared/issued, not the state of order. Thanks for you help.

Comment: ooh yes I understand, but the enum would be a typing for a histotyric table, that is, you would have a row for each type of the enum, thus making a relationship much simpler and easier to map

Comment: If I understand correctly, you propose the following intermediate table:   
| OrderId | StoreId | enum value (GettingStore/PreparingStore/IssuanceStore) |   
Right?